# Initial test scenario runs despite that the test was changed

Tags: javascript, cypress

I build react project locally. Created test scenario in cypress, run it by clicking on it, it failed. Then I changed it and run again, but it still fails at the same step that was fixed. 
Then I run test scenario by clicking `run all specs` button. The test run and the previous step was passed but failed at another one. I fixed it and run again, but it fails at the same place despite that it was changed. 
Does anybody know how to fix this problem? cypress version 3.2.0

```
    describe('Calculate the Budget', () => {

    it('Add an item to budget', () => {
        cy
            .visit('http://localhost:8000/budget')
        cy
            .get('select').select('Car')
        cy
            .get(':nth-child(2) > input')
            .type('Rent')
        cy
            .get(':nth-child(3) > input')
            .type('320')
        cy
            .get('.submit').select('Car')
        cy
            .get(':nth-child(7) > .MBPvA > ._3-t-g')
            .should('have.text', '-$320.00')
        cy
            .get(':nth-child(5) > ._3S2Fs > .sG1fB')
            .should('have.text', '$1,893.93')
})
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your spec code, and where it is failing? It sounds like you're [maintaining state between requests, which is an anti-pattern](https://on.cypress.io/best-practices#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests) - but without your spec code it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Do you have any other specs that run before this one when you do "run all tests"? Is a network request being made when `.submit` is clicked? You might need to `cy.wait()` for that network request to complete before continuing to do your `have.text` assertions.

Comment: no I don't any specs there, this is the only one. This is the problem actually, if I add something in this spec, it just doesn't see anything only initial part of the spec that failed. Seems like the state of the spec was frozen.